# ACCESS SQL - Joining 2 tables on Datetime values

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an issue joining 2 tables with datetime values in Access.
I tried to join the tables by simply setting

```
LEFT JOIN Table1.Datetime=Table2.Datetime
```

However, the output of my query is really off.
I then tried to join by splitting the dates:

```
LEFT JOIN YEAR(Table1.Datetime)=YEAR(Table2.Datetime)
AND MONTH(Table1.Datetime)=MONTH(Table2.Datetime)
AND DAY(Table1.Datetime)=DAY(Table2.Datetime)
AND HOUR(Table1.Datetime)=HOUR(Table2.Datetime)
```

Running it this way, the query seems stucked and I don't ever get any results.
I then tied joining both table on a condition like:

```
LEFT JOIN Table1.Datetime>=Table2.Datetime
AND Table1.Datetime<Table2.Datetime + 1/24
```

I'm running out of ideas for my join to effectively work, any help would be much appreciated !

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: "Table1.Datetime=Table2.Datetime"  ... the column looks like it contains detailed time too, the join will use the whole value for join. example-data is really required

Comment: After join should follow ON and specify the relation between tables. The query must start with SELECT. Check more info on the internet on how to use SELECT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*DateTime* is based on *Double*, and you can't just check such values for equality because of potential floating point errors.

Try something like this:

```
LEFT JOIN Abs(Table1.Datetime-Table2.Datetime) < #00:00:01#
```

or:

```
LEFT JOIN DateDiff("s", Table1.Datetime, Table2.Datetime) = 0
```

or:

```
LEFT JOIN Format(Table1.Datetime, yyyymmddhhnnss") = Format(Table2.Datetime, yyyymmddhhnnss")
```

These may be too slow, however. If so, join two simple select queries, one for each table, having:

```
Format(Table1.Datetime, "yyyymmddhhnnss") As TextTime  - and
Format(Table2.Datetime, "yyyymmddhhnnss") As TextTime
```

and then join on

```
query1.TextTime = query2.TextTime
```

Comment: Thank you for the ideas. However, I tried both but it resulted to a not responding Access, like before ! I am currently considering treating it in VBA with the help of recordset, zould that be a good idea ?
I can also explain you more in detail what i´m trying to achieve

Comment: Such joins are slow. Be patient. If not, change the queries to append queries and write the modified data to two (temporary) tables. Add an index to TextTime. Now you can create a normal join between the TextTime fields of the two tables.

Comment: I did insert the data with another colum "TextTime" and it worked like a charm ! Thank you !